# How to reconnect a datanode to a cluster after formatting the namenode

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I first deployed a pseudo distributed system and then converted it into fully distributed and and formatted my namnode and now the datanode that I had in pseudo distributed isn't connceting to my name node 
PS: the namenode I used for pseud is what I am using as a namnode in the fully distributed system

Answer (score 2):

You need to do something like this:

- `bin/stop-all.sh (or stop-dfs.sh and stop-yarn.sh in the 2.x series)`
- `rm -Rf /app/tmp/hadoop-your-username/*`
- `bin/hadoop namenode -format`

Refer this link: http://pages.cs.brandeis.edu/~cs147a/lab/hadoop-troubleshooting/

Answer (score 1):

if u formatted namenode then change namenode **namespaceID** which same of datanode **namespaceID** .after formating change datanode and namenode **namespaceID** then problem create. for namespaceID goes to ***/datanodefolder/current/VERSION*** and check

i think u also formate datanode and then start datanode

> **hadoop datanode  -format**